# Making the bookmarks for each answer more accessible?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, bookmark

Currently, if I want to create a direct link to an specific answer I have to:

1. Right click on the answer.
2. Select "Inspect Element".

[image]

3. Find the empty bookmark e.g. `<a name="4580130"></a>`

[image]

4. Append # to the end of the hyperlink.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580101/python-add-pythonpath-during-command-line-module-run#4580130`

5. Copy and paste this hyperlink some other place.

I'm finding myself doing this a lot and thought there might be a better way.

Also, some users are not even aware that each answer has a bookmark in the first place. The effort was made to generate the bookmarks. Why not make them more available?

Consider [this alternative](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#command-reference). When you mouse over the text "Command Reference" a paragraph symbol appears.  If I click the paragraph symbol the hyperlink with the bookmark is added to the address bar.

Do you like this idea, or do you have a better one for making the bookmark links for answers more accessible?

Comment: You absolutely don't have to do that!

Comment: FYI, if you want to share a link to a comment, the timestamp is a link to that comment.

Comment: @Will I see.  I'm glad I asked this. Now I'm learning things I never knew.

Answer (score 2):

#### Currently, if I want to create a direct link to an specific answer I have to:

> 1. Right click on the answer.
> 2. Select "Inspect Element".

Snip rest of steps.

There is a much easier solution:

1. Scroll to the bottom of the answer.
2. Click "share"

[image]

3. You will see a link.

   Raw link text:

   > `[Making the bookmarks for each answer more accessible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316269/3536342)`
4. Copy the link.
5. (optional) remove your user id from the end of the link.
6. Paste it somewhere:

   [Making the bookmarks for each answer more accessible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316269/3536342).

Or:

1. Scroll to the bottom of the answer.
2. Right click share and select "Copy Link Location" (in Firefox)

   Raw link text:

   > `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316269/3536342`
3. (optional) remove your user id from the end of the link.
4. Paste it somewhere:

   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316269/3536342

---

#### Why is my user id in the share link?

Corrected as per comment by [Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra)

Your user id is [1783439](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1783439/nu-everest).

The first number ([316269](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316268/making-the-bookmarks-for-each-answer-more-accessible/316269#316269)) is the **not your user id** it is the post id, which is so the link actually points to the correct post on the page.

The second id ([3536342](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3536342/davidpostill)) is a user id (in this case mine), and it's the sharer's user id (whoever clicks the link, while logged in), and that is for the purpose of tracking badges, specifically [Announcer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/60/booster), and [Publicist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist).

Comment: @Servy Good point. Will update the answer.

Comment: I've been using stackoverflow for about 3 years, and I've never noticed the share link.

Comment: Why is my user id in the share link?

Comment: @nueverest Because the link I chose to share as an example is a link to an answer to **your** question. My user id is at the end of the link because it a link to this answer (**my answer**) to the question. Answer updated.

Comment: That's not the reason the user id is in the share link, and that's not nu everest's user id. The first number is the _post_ id, which is so the link actually points to the correct post on the page. Only the _second_ link is a user id, and it's the _sharer's_ user id (whoever clicks the link, while logged in), and that is for the purpose of tracking badges, specifically [Announcer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [Booster](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/60/booster), and [Publicist.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist) cc @nueverest

Comment: @Kendra. Ah so it is. I will correct the answer.

Comment: This is really not obvious :-(